# Commands suggested by apropos are not working

Tags: linux, command-line, apropos

I was trying to look for encryption commands with apropos:

```
apropos encrypt
```

A lot of them don't work, for example: gpgsm, setkey, passwd2des etc.
When I type them I just get:

```
bash: command_name: command not found
```

Any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

`apropos` doesn’t suggest commands, it suggests manpages; some of them will correspond to commands, but not all of them, and even those that correspond to commands might not correspond to commands which are accessible to you.

`apropos`’ output gives some idea of the kind of documentation it’s listing:

```
key_encryptsession (3) - interfaces to rpc keyserver daemon
letsencrypt (1)      - certbot script documentation
luksformat (8)       - Create and format an encrypted LUKS device
```

The numbers in parentheses correspond to [sections](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/man.1.html#DESCRIPTION): if you’re looking for end-user commands, look for 1 here (as shown for `letsencrypt`) above.

Try

```
man gpgsm
man setkey
```

etc. to view the documentation found by `apropos`, instead of running the commands.

Comment: ...and pay attention to the _section_ the page is in (inside parenthesis in the header of footer). `man man; man -a intro` may be a good start.

Comment: So there is no way to use the commands that don't have (1)?